# Add a custom label to material range slider

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, rangeslider, android-slider

I'm using Android material components library's latest (1.3.0-alpha01) version  to display a range slider (slider with two thumbs). Now need to customize the labels and **always** show each thumb's value over the thumbs in TextView (without any drawables or default flags, see attached picture). How can I make `labelBehavior` always visible and show the thumb values in custom view when user drags them?
[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To change the **background color** of the label you can use a custom style:

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        style="@style/Myslider"
        ...>
```

with:

```
<style name="Myslider" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Slider">
    <item name="labelStyle">@style/My_Tooltip</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Slider</item>
</style>

<style name="My_Tooltip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
    <!-- background color of the Tooltip -->
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/...</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Slider" parent="">
    <!-- color used by the text in the Tooltip -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

To customize the value in the label you can a **`LabelFormatter`**.
Something like:

```
RangeSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
slider.setLabelFormatter(new LabelFormatter() {
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    //It is just an example
    if (value == 3.0f)
      return "TEST";
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%.0f", value);
  }
});
```

[image]

About the **behavior** of the label there are only these values (with `1.2.0-beta01` and `1.3.0-alpha01)`:

- `LABEL_FLOATING`: The label will only be visible on interaction. It will float above the slider and may cover views above this one. This is the default and recommended behavior.
- `LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS`: The label will only be visible on interaction. The label will always be drawn within the bounds of this view. This means extra space will be visible above the slider when the label is not visible.
- `LABEL_GONE`: The label will never be drawn.

Currently it seems impossible to show always the label.

You can set the label behavior using the `setLabelBehavior` method or the `labelBehavior` in the layout or in a style.

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        app:labelBehavior="withinBounds"/>
```

If you want to change the **shape** of the label you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58499669/2016562).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to change the grey label itself, not just format its value.

Comment: Thank you. But again, I need to change the label and put values above the thumbs. I've updated the question and added a screenshot so you can see what I mean

Comment: @Lara Sorry I red about "change the grey". You can customize the background and the text color of the Tooltip (label). You could use the same color of the background (but the label is not so close to the track). But I am unable to have the label always shown.

Comment: Anyways thanks again for help. Hope they will add the ability to always show the labels soon ;)

Comment: How to set LABEL_GONE directly from the xml? Where can I find the docs regarding LABEL_FLOATING, LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS, and LABEL_GONE? Thanks

Comment: @nibbana Updated the answer. Just use `app:labelBehavior` in the layout or `<item name="labelBehavior">withinBounds</item>` in a style.

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti, this answer has helped me. I want to ask how did you to find which attributes to modify? I am unable to find this info from documentation, do you just go and read the source code directly? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @GabrieleMariotti I just wanted to know if I can give the trackActiveColor a gradient drawable or is there a way I can set a gradient for it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This should have been a comment, but I can't comment so here it is.
As Gabriele already told you, you can't permanently stick the label (`TooltipDrawable`) above the thumb. In fact, you should override few methods of `BaseSlider`, but they rely on private fields.

I also wanted to say (to the visitors) that I couldn't change the label's text color as Gabriele said. I have version `1.3.0-alpha01`.
I had to do restyle another component, `TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Tooltip`.

*my_layout.xml*

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    ...
    app:labelStyle="@style/MyTooltip"
    ...
/>
```

*res/values/styles.xml:*

```
<style name="MyTooltip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
    <item name="backgroundTint">...</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTooltip.TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTooltip.TextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
    <item name="android:textColor">...</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">...</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">...</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">...</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I want to follow up with Gabrielle, specifically for relabeling the Material slider.

When implementing something like:

```
RangeSlider slider = findViewById(R.id.slider);
slider.setLabelFormatter(new LabelFormatter() {
  @NonNull
  @Override
  public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    //It is just an example
    if (value == 3.0f)
      return "TEST";
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%.0f", value);
  }
});
```

Be sure to correctly determine the type of the Slider. If you're using material.Slider, then you need to change `RangeSlider` to `Slider` since Android cannot automatically cast the data type for you.