# material slider and range slider tooltip not always visible

Tags: android, material-components-android

i wanted to keep the tooltip value visible always and also the text of tooltip should be background transparent.
i tried https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md but there no way to keep the tooltip always visible

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/slider_sound_sensitivity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.508"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_sound_sensitivity" />

<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
        android:id="@+id/range_humidity_in_percentage"
        style="@style/Myslider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="100.0"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_humidity_in_percentage"
        app:values="@array/initial_slider_values" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a custom label to material range slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245234/add-a-custom-label-to-material-range-slider)

Comment: no still the tooltip gets gone

Answer (score 17):

**From Material Design 1.6.0 and above** **('com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'):**

There is an official attribute `app:labelBehavior="visible"` as suggested by @S.Gissel on his answer like the below:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    app:labelBehavior="visible"/>

<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
    app:labelBehavior="visible"/>
```

**From  Material Design 1.5.0 and below:**

There was no public API to keep the Tooltip always visible using the app:labelBehavior attribute. Below is a workaround using a Reflection:

1. Create a Subclass of a Slider/RangeSlider and override the `onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas)` method and call the `setSliderTooltipAlwaysVisible(Slider slider)` method to keep the Tooltip always visible like below:

   **For Slider:**

   ```
    public class MyCustomSlider extends Slider {

    public MyCustomSlider(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomSlider(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomSlider(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //in case this View is inside a ScrollView you can listen to OnScrollChangedListener to redraw the View
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        setSliderTooltipAlwaysVisible(this);
    }

    public static void setSliderTooltipAlwaysVisible(Slider slider){

        try
        {
            Class<?> baseSliderCls = Slider.class.getSuperclass();
            if (baseSliderCls != null) {

                Method ensureLabelsAddedMethod = baseSliderCls.getDeclaredMethod("ensureLabelsAdded");
                ensureLabelsAddedMethod.setAccessible(true);
                ensureLabelsAddedMethod.invoke(slider);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }
   ```

   **For RangeSlider:**

   ```
    public class MyCustomRangeSlider extends RangeSlider {

    public MyCustomRangeSlider(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomRangeSlider(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomRangeSlider(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //in case this View is inside a ScrollView you can listen to OnScrollChangedListener to redraw the View
        getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        setSliderTooltipAlwaysVisible(this);
    }

    public static void setSliderTooltipAlwaysVisible(RangeSlider slider){

        try
        {
            Class<?> baseSliderCls = RangeSlider.class.getSuperclass();
            if (baseSliderCls != null) {

                Method ensureLabelsAddedMethod = baseSliderCls.getDeclaredMethod("ensureLabelsAdded");
                ensureLabelsAddedMethod.setAccessible(true);
                ensureLabelsAddedMethod.invoke(slider);
            }
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
   }
   ```

   The key point here is to call the private method `private void ensureLabelsAdded()` of BaseSlider class using a Reflection after the `super.onDraw(canvas)` gets called.
2. Use the above custom Sliders in your xml like below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <my.package.name.MyCustomSlider
       style="@style/Widget.App.Slider"
       app:labelBehavior="floating"
       android:id="@+id/slider_sound_sensitivity"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:valueFrom="0.0"
       android:valueTo="100.0"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

   <my.package.name.MyCustomRangeSlider
       style="@style/Widget.App.Slider"
       app:labelBehavior="floating"
       android:id="@+id/range_humidity_in_percentage"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:valueFrom="0.0"
       android:valueTo="100.0"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slider_sound_sensitivity"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:values="@array/initial_slider_values" />

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

**Note:** In case you still need to use this workaround in Material Design 1.6.0 you have to change from the above xml the attribute `app:labelBehavior="floating"` to `app:labelBehavior="visible"` in both
MyCustomSlider/MyCustomRangeSlider.

And `style="@style/Widget.App.Slider"` is your custom style defined in styles.xml file like below:

```
   <style name="Widget.App.Slider" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Slider">
        <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.Slider</item>
        <item name="labelStyle">@style/Widget.App.Tooltip</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ThemeOverlay.App.Slider" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Tooltip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.App.Tooltip</item>
        <!--This is the Tooltip Background Color. In case you don't want a background change it to @android:color/transparent -->
        <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/holo_orange_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.Tooltip" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Tooltip">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
    </style>
```

From the above xml you can change the Tooltip Background to Transparent color by changing the backgroundTint color:  `<item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>`.

**Results with a Tooltip always visible with a Transparent background:**

[image: slider_transparent_tooltip]

**Results with a Tooltip always visible with a Non-Transparent background:**

[image: slider_non_transparent_tooltip]

Comment: This solution is wonderful on first sight. I implemented it, but inside a scrollview the tooltip stays, while the rest scrolls. :-/

Comment: @S.Gissel yes you are right i didn't test it inside a ScrollView now it has been fixed you have to invalidate() the View when the scroll is changed. Check updated answer. Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: please see my answer to this question. Finally a native way to add a label constantly.

Comment: If used in a ScrollView, then labels don't move while the rest scrolls

Comment: @phazei There is a bug in the Material library in case is used in a ScrollView, you can follow the workaround in the answer to fix it by implementing the section **"From Material Design 1.5.0 and below"** and in the xml use the attribute `app:labelBehavior="visible"` from  Material Design 1.6.0 and above.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Material Slider has not state of label for **ALWAYS VISIBLE**.
But we can do one thing to overcome this issue.
First we have to make `app:labelBehavior:gone` in Material Slider.

We have to put TextView above Slider in .xml file. You can apply different background to TextView. In below code **`tvSlider`** is an id of TextView.

Then call `addOnChangeListener` method of Material Slider, And use below code.

```
slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
            tvSlider.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(value)));
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateValueLabelPosition();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Below method is for sliding TextView with Slider.

```
private void updateValueLabelPosition() {
    float valueRangeSize = slider.getValueTo() - slider.getValueFrom();
    float valuePercent = (slider.getValue() - slider.getValueFrom()) / valueRangeSize;
    float valueXDistance = valuePercent * slider.getTrackWidth();
    float offset = slider.getX() + slider.getTrackSidePadding() - ((float) tvSlider.getWidth() / 2);
    tvSlider.setX(valueXDistance + offset);
}
```

That's it![image: Material Slider with Custom label]

Answer (score 3):

@mariosP's answer is valid and good. But in Material library 1.6.0 Google added a native way to add a label that's always visible.

`<Slider app:labelBehavior="visible" />` does the same job.

In fact it is even dangerous upgrading to 1.6.0 and still using a MyCustomSlider as in @mariosP's solution. The ondraw() method is called infinitely and no label is showing anymore. Be careful.

Comment: Finally an official way to handle this in Material Design 1.6.0 and above. The only issue is if the Slider/RangeSlider is inside a ScrollView the Tooltip doesn't scroll with the rest components and stays to its initial position on the screen. Hope to fix this also soon.+1

Comment: After upgrading to 1.6.0, you can avoid the infinitely issue if you change in MyCustomSlider xml file the attribute
app:labelBehavior="floating"  to app:labelBehavior="visible" and the Tooltip it will still works inside a ScrollView until we have an official fix from Google. Good point thank you.