# How to show slider value above the slider also when we are not sliding using material.slider in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, slider, material-components-android

This is how I want to show the value of the slider. Please find the picture

[image: Sample slider image]

Comment: Currently there is no public API to show Slider label always visible. One possible solution for now is using a Reflection check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613186/material-slider-and-range-slider-tooltip-not-always-visible/68711632#68711632

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported, the available options in `LabelFormatter` (which can be applied to sliders with `slider.setLabelFormatter(...)` are:

- `LabelFormatter.LABEL_FLOATING`: Label visible during interaction only
- `LabelFormatter.LABEL_WITHIN_BOUNDS`: Label visible during interaction only
- `LabelFormatter.LABEL_GONE`: Label never visible

You can find the code [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/2d589bd351e59b461eab19cc7461c129c6a33c41/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/BaseSlider.java#L301-L314) with the extensive javadoc explanation.

You could open a feature request for this on the Material GitHub [issues page](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the label behaviour "visible" in the XML file. So in the slider XML code, you just need to add

```
app:labelBehavior="visible"
```

Below I am attaching a sample XML code for the same.

```
    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="100"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:tickColor="#0000FF"
        app:labelStyle="@style/Tooltip"
        app:labelBehavior="visible"
        />
```