# How can I add a custom label to each tick on a slider in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, slider

I'm trying to make an app with a slider where each tick has a label. An example will be types of t shirt sizes. So each tick would be a certain price and then I'll take the results of each slider and add them all together.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've been googling. I haven't been able to come up with anything other than this for the labeling https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245234/add-a-custom-label-to-material-range-slider But in terms of adding them all up I haven't even found a way.

Comment: Are you really just asking how to get the selected value from a slider?